# Converting a string to a class type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am wanting to convert a string into a class type.

```
func getViewController(sbName: String, vcName: String, vcType: String) -> UIViewController{
    let classType = ????? //What to put here?
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: sbName, bundle: nil)
    var vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcName) as classType

    return vc 
}
```

If anyone could lead me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it! I have a feeling there is a way to do it but have not been able to find a way how.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only worried about Objective-C based classes, you can use         `NSClassFromString("ClassName")`

However, your method is returning UIViewController explicitly. Casting vc to the class type is not going to help you at all.

Perhaps a generic method would be better for you:

```
func getViewController<T: UIViewController>(sbName: String, vcName: String) -> T {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: sbName, bundle: nil)
    var vc = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vcName) as T
    return vc
}
```

The type can then be inferred from the variable you are trying to assign this to:

```
var viewController: MyViewController = getViewController("ASDF", "ASDF")
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue too. Your answer should be accepted!